# Odd spacing in combination of reledmac and quoting

Tags: quoting, reledmac

In the following example the last line of the quoting environment has an odd vertical spacing. I intend to use the quoting package mainly for the possibility of setting `rightmargin=0cm`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[rightmargin=0cm,vskip=0cm,indentfirst=false]{quoting}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{ledgroup}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\begin{quoting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{quoting}
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{ledgroup}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, I would like to have the same vertical spacing between all the lines.

Comment: It is explicitly mentionned in the handbook of reledmac that there is a truble and specific rules when dealing with quote environment...

Comment: @Maïeul Okay. I now inserted `\mbox{}` between `\pstart`, the `quoting` environment, and `\pend`, and that at least fixes the odd spacing of the very last line of the `quoting` environment. But I assume that reledmac and the quoting package including its environment have not been optimised to work together?

Comment: YOu assume well